# Git and Puppet Master Lifecycle

Tags: git, puppet

I'm looking to setup a Puppet Master which hosts its configuration in a Git repository.

I assume that I'd host my Puppet Configuration in a Git repository centrally organized on a Git hosting service like GitLab or GitHub. I assume that I'd have commit hooks which would trigger the Puppet Master server to pull the changes down to its local repository.

Does a project or a tutorial exist on how to set this up? I'm simply looking to be able to automate configuration of my servers in a way as minimally complicated as possible.

Comment: This book has the entire workflow detailed: http://www.packtpub.com/puppet-3-beginners-guide/book

Comment: This should get you 95% of the way there: http://www.tokiwinter.com/implementing-git-dynamic-workflows-puppet/

Comment: Here's an [archive.today link](http://archive.today/m1zlV) for the tokiwinter link (no DNS for it at present).